# Integrate the script and parameterised build code in Jenkins pipeline item to github

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have centralized deployment that is created as a "pipeline" item on Jenkins.

All of the services can be deployed from UAT to PRD using this pipeline.

### How it works:

This pipeline has the feature of:

- **Parameterised build**

  - You can select "Service" <- provides dropdown of different services
  - Depending on the service, you can see the corresponding "Source location"(UAT server), and "Destination"(PRD server) <- a list of `if else` cases configured in Jenkins
- **the pipeline itself**: put as a **script** for this pipeline item

### Problem:

There is:

- No version control
- The script only stored in Jenkins. In case we lose Jenkins, the script will be gone.
- Whenever we update, we update the script on Jenkins directly (work on it on VS code, copy & paste it to this  Jenkins item)

### Question:

- How to/ Is it possible to store the groovy script & parameterised build code on github repo and have them auto-update the Jenkins pipeline directly?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Jenkins pipeline **configuration** menu, you can indicate a GitHub repository to pull and execute the Jenkinsfile script from, like shown below.

Then, if you want your pipeline script to run on every *git push*, you must setup a webhook within your GitHub repository that points to the Jenkins URL, and finally, activate the `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling` checkbox in the pipeline configuration menu.

Do not forget to have the **[GitHub plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/)** installed.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out. I wonder if it's also possible to store the groovy script in "Active Choices Parameters" of Parameterised build in github?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe so.. What I advise you to do regardless, is to store the `config.xml` file in your GitHub repo, just to have it as a backup if something goes wrong with the server. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'Accepted', thank you! :)